# Update drawing with a button in Jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, widget

I'm trying to mimic [this example](https://github.com/markjay4k/fourier-transform/blob/master/widgets_example.ipynb) of using widgets of Jupyter notebooks to redraw a figure interactively. The difference I want to introduce is that the figure I'm producing is rather heavy (computationally), so I'd like that the kernel wait until I explicitly press an "upload button". I have tried to get this behaviour with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

freq = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, value=0.5, max=10.0, step=0.5,description='freq:')
redraw = widgets.Button(description='Redraw',button_style='')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1,figsize=(5,3), )

def update(a):
    x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
    y = np.sin(freq.value*x)

    ax.clear()
    plt.plot(x, y)

display(freq, redraw)
redraw.on_click(update)
```

It more or less works, but the problem is that I get a copy of the figure below. In other words, the figure is not refreshed, but reploted below.

How can I get a proper refreshment of the figure that mimics the behaviour in the example I'm using?

PS: on a side note, why do I need the dummy argument "a" in the function update? It seems that otherwise it does not work...

Comment: Answering the side-note: matplotlib callbacks are called with an `Event` as argument. So your function signature needs to take this event as input, even if you don't use it. (I usually use `def update(event=None)` to make it clear that the function would work even without an event passed on to it.